# MYSQL update records on a where condition depending from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I get error that subquery returns more than one row. How to solve this:

```
UPDATE sales
    SET newsletter='0'
    WHERE (user_id='33' AND product_id=(SELECT product_id FROM phplist_list WHERE id = (SELECT listid FROM phplist_listmessage WHERE messageid='20')))
```

Comment: Why all the subselects?  Why not UPDATE across a join?

Comment: IS it possible for you to help me by writing the example above using a JOIN? Thanks, cause I am not expert in sql, I lost my exercise quite several years ago about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using `in` instead of `=`:

```
UPDATE sales
    SET newsletter='0'
    WHERE user_id = '33' AND
          product_id in (SELECT product_id
                         FROM phplist_list
                         WHERE id in (SELECT listid
                                      FROM phplist_listmessage
                                      WHERE messageid = '20'
                                     )
                        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I use mysql coding quite seldom now and I had forgot the difference between using "in" and using a "=" in the query condition